# Can't access certain specific IP/domain on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, wireless-router, ip

Been banging my head on the wall for some time now.

I have a fresh install of Windows 7 - Ultimate ~x86.  Some IPs can't resolve properly, it doesn't matter if I try using Firefox, Chrome or IE I end up with a domain not found (server not found, etc.)

I am behind a router, all the other computers aren't affected only this Win 7 machine.  It's only certain sites.

e.g. xkcd.com, facebook's cdn, google group.

Things I have tried:

- flushdns
- ipconfig renew
- Disable IP v6 on the NIC
- Double checked that the computer was in the right timezone @ the right time.
- Reinstall the NIC driver.

Again 90% of the sites will work but not the major one :P help!!!

**EDIT:** I tried using Google's public dns server @ 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4 as an alternative and it worked fine so it's now down to a DNS problem.  What doesn't make sense is that using the same DNS all the others computers on the network can access those sites (a mix of iPhone, HTC Magic, xbox 360, XP and Windows Vista).

Comment: Do any of these domains appear in your hosts file (%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)?  Could be a source of interference.

Comment: @Jeff M there is nothing in the host file but the standard commented out text.  # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost

Comment: Change your DNS servers to Open DNS in your tcp/ip properties...http://theos.in/windows-xp/free-fast-public-dns-server-list/

Comment: @Moab yes it works using an OpenDNS provider.  What I don't understand is why this is the only computer on this network where it will not work using the one provided by my router (and therefore ISP)

Comment: usually I am so glad it works, I don't question why, strange problem indeed. Set the DNS in the router to Open DNS servers, see if this cures it.

Comment: @Moab yeah if I set the router to an Open DNS server it assign me that by DHCP and it works.  It seems to be a problem with the one provided by my ISP but it's working for every other devices on the network... strange.

Comment: So after switching the router to OpenDNS I switched back to the one provided by my ISP and I got a new one assigned to me.  Everything is back to normal... I don't get it but eh, like you said I am just glad it work this time.  Looks like the problem was at their end, maybe IPv6 related? I have that disabled but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure DNS service on the machine is running.

Ping and tracert those sites. See what you get back.

Comment: @alpha1 DNS client is running, I can ping the IP but not by domain so its definitely dns that is not resolving.  Ping/tracert on the domain doesn't resolve.

Comment: @alpha1 See my edit in the OP.  I tried Google's DNS and it worked but the stange thing is that all the other computer using the router's dns (from my ISP) can get to those sites.

Comment: Turn off the firewall, and any anti spyware etc and try it then. Something could be blocking the DNS port (It could also be a virus or something of that sort so make sure to turn everything back on)

Comment: @alpha1 I tried with and without the firewall, no difference.  There is no antivirus or antispyware.  It's a fresh install of Windows that I did before the holidays so I could rdp into work from my parents.  Nothing else ran on it but an rdp session and the occasional visit to facebook (where I initially noticed the problem.)

Comment: And you did updates drivers and such?

Comment: Could it be some kinda of authorization problem, like is your router mac address secure, where its verifying your computer, or anything of that sort. WEP key? Try removing it? Does it happen on wired and wifi?

Comment: Also could try hardcoding those IPs of those troubled sites into your hosts file. See if that speeds it up.

Comment: @alpha I did update the drivers.  Wish I could do more test but unfortunately I am now back at home.  This was happening at my sister's who I was visiting during the holidays... I never did fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Also check your firewall logs and anti virus logs to doublecheck that they are not blocking these sites e.g. by proxying the requests.

Comment: There are no installed anti virus at the moment as it's a fresh install.  The only firewall was the Windows firewall that is enabled by default.  I tried disabling it and it didn't resolve the issue.